# dotnet application in GKE with nginx ingress controller and proxy

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a dotnet application running on Kestrel and hosting it in a Linux container on GKE. Alongside the container, I am running a sidecar nginx container to proxy to it. I've read that Kestrel isn't as feature rich thus including the nginx sidecar.

The issue I am having is I either keep getting a 502 or 404 not found. Running local curl requests following redirects does work though.

This returns a proper response from my nginx -> Kestrel

```
curl -vL "http://127.0.0.1"
```

Hitting it externally through the public lb,

```
response 404 (backend NotFound), service rules for [ /index.html ] non-existent
``

This is my nginx.conf

worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream web-api {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name $hostname;

        location /nginx-health {
             return 200 "healthy\n";
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://web-api;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

My Ingress

```
Name:             app
Namespace:        app
Address:          34.120.149.155
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  app-tls terminates external_url
Rules:
  Host                                   Path  Backends
  ----                                   ----  --------
  <external_url>
                                         /   app:80 (10.108.21.149:80)
Annotations:
  certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer:            letsencrypt
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:        k8s2-fr-6bwo4q66-app-2jv0uft5
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule:  k8s2-fs-6bwo4q66-app-2jv0uft5
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy:     k8s2-ts-6bwo4q66-app-2jv0uft5
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:           k8s2-tp-6bwo4q66-app-2jv0uft5
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                k8s2-um-6bwo4q66-app-2jv0uft5
  meta.helm.sh/release-name:                    app
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:               {"k8s-be-30587--b22f31f8e3f41440":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31967--b22f31f8e3f41440":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert:               k8s2-cr-6bwo4q66-rn3hwilrxhwvg79m-506e1c732112861c
  ingress.kubernetes.io/static-ip:              k8s2-fr-6bwo4q66-labs-createstudio-createdataservice-2jv0uft5
  meta.helm.sh/release-namespace:               app
```

My service

```
Name:                     app
Namespace:                app
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=app
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=app
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.1.0
                          helm.sh/chart=app-0.1.0
Annotations:              beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: {"ports": {"80":"app-config"}}
                          meta.helm.sh/release-name: app
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: app
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=app,app.kubernetes.io/name=app
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.181.45.135
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30587/TCP
Endpoints:                10.108.21.149:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I updated all the names/namespaces/urls to something more generic so I do not expose too much information on my app.

I have a feeling its due to the ingress path on the host being just `/`.

I have also noticed that when hitting nginx externally, I get a 301 redirect which proxies to the Kestrel server. After that Kestrel returns the 301 to nginx and I feel like this is where the loop is. Ie, when Kestrel returns the response, it goes out through the external URL again and sends the request back to nginx from the outside. Hope that makes sense.

Hope anyone could shed some light on this. Cheers!

Comment: It's unclear why are you using the nginx sidecar, is there any feature you need from it? If not, it feels unnecessary in your current design.

Comment: Hey Yaron, I was basing it off of the documentation on building with Linux and having a reverse proxy. This is my first ever dotnet application deployment in kubernetes so it's a bit new. Typically I would have a sidecar and send traffic to php-fpm or wsgi. So I naturally though to take this same approach. Here is the link to the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Take look at the list of feature in the documentation that are covered by a reverse proxy. I think GKE ingress controller can take care of most of them for you, so you can drop the nginx sidecar unless it has a specific use and just route requests directly to your application container.

Comment: Cheers Yaron I will re review the docs and report back. Do you know if kestrel can scale the same way as php-fpm or wsgi?

Comment: I'm not familiar with both of php-fpm and wsgi well enough but I'm also not sure what do you mean by scale, in Kubernetes you will probably scale your application horizontally and create additional instances of kestrel and your app.

Comment: No problem, just in the sense of processes/workers/threads etc to handle requests

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna add my initial comment as an answer, if it ends up serving you well - feel free to mark it as the correct answer for anyone else stumbling over the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GKE ingress controller can act as a reverse proxy for you (providing SSL termination, for example), there is no need to add an nginx sidecar, and you can route your requests directly to your container application.